# Calling .exe file in C program

Tags: c, exe

I am having an util.exe file and I want to call it in my C program. Also my utils.exe file takes two    values as arguments.
Can any one suggest how to do it?

Comment: which platform are you using

Comment: I am using windows..

Comment: Most systems have a function called `system`. Use a search engine to find the documentation for it for your platform.

Comment: It is operating system specific. You might use [system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html), [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html), [execve](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html) (assuming you have a POSIX compliant operating system). Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Comment: Include stdlib.h in your .C file and use system function (for example->system("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");)

Answer (score 5):

You could build an entire command line, e.g.

```
 char cmdbuf[80];
 snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "somefile.exe %d %d", i+j, i*j);
```

(actually, you should test the result of `snprintf` and be sure it is less than `sizeof(cmdbuf)`....)

Then pass it to [system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) (read carefully the documentation of *your* `system` function, as provided by *your* operating system).

```
 int retcod = system(cmdbuf);
```

Be very careful about [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection); you probably should quote or escape or sanitize or validate any argument passed on the command line (going into `cmdbuf`). This is very [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [command shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) specific.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `system()` function for which you will have to include `stdlib.h` in your program. Since you are on windows,you can use

```
system("myfile.exe");
```

in your program to open `myfile.exe`.Note that if `myfile.exe` is not in the directory of your program,then you'll have to provide the full path for `system` like this:

```
system("C:\\folder\\myfile.exe");
```

Comment: how to I pass the arguments

Comment: @user3797438 , `system("myfile.exe firstargument secondargument");` .

Comment: @user3797438 if the `firstargument` is an variable, does it still retain its value or the whole command is passed as a string ?

Comment: @user3656142 `system("myfile.exe firstargument secondargument");` will pass `firstargument` and `secondargument` as a string regardless of whether there's a variable with those names. If you'd like to use the variable's value, you'll need to use `sprintf` or `snprintf` as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817217/3049655) shows